# Hermitian operators check

Tags: functions

[image: df]
Is there a way to use Mathematica to check whether an operator in Quantum mechanics is hermitian. This way I can check above momentum operator is hermitian or not in Mathematica. Similarly I can answer below questions.
[image: vhh]

Comment: Why do you want to do it with Mathematica?

Comment: As I mentioned above, any code that helps to check whether an operator is hermitian or not?

Comment: The question of operator Hermiticity is not that simple. For instance $\hat{p}$ is Hermitian on $(-\infty,\infty)$, but is not Hermitian on the $[0,\infty)$ interval. Have a look at this article https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.1328351. One needs to teach Mathematica the Weyl-von Neumann theorem, which is nontrivial.